# Shell command to list file names where the matching is found

Tags: shell, grep, pipe

I am trying to search through a list of binary files to find some keywords on Mac.

The following works to list out all the matches, but it doesn't show me the list of files where it is being found:

```
find . -type f -exec strings {} \;|grep "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4"
```

Is there any trick to do this?

Comment: Do you still want to print the matches, or *just* the files’ names/paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `-exec` with a wee ‘script’:

```
find . -type f \
       -exec sh -c 'strings "$1" | grep -q "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4"' -- {} \; \
       -print
```

The above will print the paths of all the matching files. If you also want to print the matches you can use:

```
find . -type f \
       -exec sh -c 'strings "$1" | grep "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4"' -- {} \; \
       -print
```

This will, however, print the paths *after* the matches. If this is not desirable, then you can use:

```
find . -type f \
       -print \
       -exec sh -c 'strings "$1" | grep "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4"' -- {} \;
```

This, on the other hand, will print *all* paths, even non-matching ones. To print *only* matching paths and their matches:

```
find . -type f \
       -exec sh -c 'strings "$1" | grep -q "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4"' -- {} \; \
       -print \
       -exec grep "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4" {} \;
```

This will run `grep` twice on matching files, which will make it slower. If this is a problem the matches can be stored in a variable, and if there are any the path printed first and then the matches. This is left as an exercise to the reader.<sup>*</sup>

<sup><sup>* Let me know if I should post it here.</sup></sup>

Comment: I've tested this one, but didn't display the content of the file.

Comment: I thought the user wanted both things, filenames and below the strings printed. In  that case grep already does that.

Comment: True, what about this: `$ grep -arl . -e 'soloman' | tee | strings --print-file-name` In this case you could redirect to strings and process there?

Answer (score -1):

Try `grep -rl "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4" .`.

Explanation of options:

- `-r`: search recursively
- `-l`: don't print the contents of the file, just print the filename.

Optionally, you might want to use `-i` to search case-insensitively.

The problem with your idea is that you're piping the output of `strings` into `grep`. The filename is only passed to `strings`, meaning that nothing that comes after `strings` knows the filename.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure about portability, but if you are using GNU's version of grep, then you can use `--files-with-matches`

```
-l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
```

Then you can use something like this:

```
grep --recursive --files-with-matches "Bv9qtsZRgspQliITY4" *
```

Comment: You’re missing the whole `strings` thing. This probably won’t work.

Comment: FYI, `-l` is portable (POSIX), but `--files-with-matches` is not (GNU).

Comment: GNU grep will search binary files. If you want to be explicit about it you can pass `-U` to specify a binary search. so the `strings` command and the associated `find` command are superfluous.

Comment: But `strings`’s output is not the same as the contents of the file, so `grep`ing it is *not* the same as `grep`ing the file, binary or not.

Comment: I agree, but the OP only wants to find filenames so the differences are not going to affect the output. Also  earlier I said `-U` I meant to say `-a`.

Comment: Yeah, almost. `strings` also doesn’t prints strings from the *whole* file, but may limit itself to strings ‘*in loadable, initialized data sections*’, so the `grep` results *might* differ. But since OP has gone missing we might never know whether that matters, or even if they want to print matches as well as filenames.

Comment: he will probably come back and wonder why people are still discussing because he solved his problem and moved onto the next as we all tend to do. There were three almost identical answers right away so he most likely used those and it worked for him.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
# this will list all the files containing given text in current directory
# i to ignore case
# l to list files with matches
# R read and process all files in that directory, recursively, following all symbolic links
grep -iRl "your-text-to-find" ./

# for case sensitive search
grep -Rl "your-text-to-find" ./
```

Comment: Adding -i could lead to incorrect strings in the search of the user.

Comment: @nandal You’re missing the whole `strings` thing. This probably won’t work.

Comment: @John, thank you, fyi, this prints out the file names, without the matches.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if it's only to print names of files don't use find but grep.

```
grep -ar . -e 'soloman' ./testo.txt:1:soloman
```

- -a : Search in binary files
- -r : recursive

And keep it simple.

If you don't want to see the words matched in your output simply add `-l, --files-with-matches`:

```
user@DESKTOP-RR909JI ~/projects/search
$ grep -arl . -e 'soloman'
./testo.txt
```